# Help with understanding some theory relating differentiation and FTC

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**If $F$ is a differentiable function, then does there exist a function $g$ such that $$F(x)=\int_a^xg(t)dt $$ ?**

My thinking: NO, because say there exists such a function $g,$ then since $F$ is differentiable, $g$ has to be continuous (by FTC) now $F'(x)=g(x),$ impling that $F'(x)$ is continuous but this was not given in the question, $F(x)$ may not have a continuous derivative.

Someone has told me that FTC doesn't say that $g$ has to be continous for $F$ to be differentiable but I have read that $g$ has to be continuous for $F$ to be differentiable, can someone explain me which is it. I am not in college yet so could you explain the answer to my question on a very crude level cause without reference to Riemann or Lebesgue integration.

Comment: If such a g existed, what would F(a) be?

Comment: zero, oh but then F vanishes at a which is not given nor is necessary, right so is the answer to the question is NO? but if suppose it is given that F(a)=0 then??

Comment: $\int_a^xg(x)dx$ doesn't make sense. You probably want $\int_a^xg(t)dt$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your integrals are of the Riemann kind, the so-called [Volterra function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) is a standard example. The Volterra function is constructed from "stitching together" translated copies of
$$
f(x)=\cases{x^2\sin(1/x)& if $x\neq0$\\0& if $x=0$}
$$
in such a way that the singularities take up a significant portion of the unit interval. It is still differentiable, like $f$. But also like $f$, its derivative is discontinuous.

In fact, the derivative of the Volterra function is discontinuous on a positive measure set, and as such not Riemann integrable; the derivative looks like the singularity of $\sin(1/x)$ way too many places for any integral to be defined. So the Volterra function is an antiderivative, but not the result of a definite integral.

Comment: I am not in college yet so could you explain the answer to my question on a very crude level cause if we were gonna go in to the details then I need to have knowledge about Riemann and Lebesgue integral

Comment: @Raunitsingh I just say Riemann integral and Riemann integrable to cover my own bases. If you aren't totally clear on the difference, and you are more on a high school level than a university level, then "Riemann" is basically superfluous, and you can take away his name entirely from my post and not worry about it for the time being.

Comment: suppose that it is given that F' is continous then I think the answer to the original questions is affirmative Right??

Comment: @Ranuitsingh If $F'$ is continuous, then yes, the FTC kicks in. You still get the problem mentioned in the comments above, though. You do have $$F(x)=\int_a^x F'(t)dt+F(a)$$but that's it. If $F(a)\neq0$, there is no such $g$.

Comment: I have couple small questions which I cant ask as a separate question as they are very basic and are 1 liners, first question what I have learned is that for F(x) to be differentiable g have to be continous, is this true?

Comment: and integral of f' from a to b =f(a)-f(b) this is true if f is continous or if f is not continous then f has to be riemann integrable Right?

Comment: I have tried to fix a typo in definition of $f$. I hope this is what you intended, but in case not then please revert back the changes and accept my apology for the edit.